# Is it possible and worth it to create a DNS server + Cache on windows 10 and cache everything?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dns, internet, cache

I was wondering if it's possible and logical to create a DNS server/cache inside Windows 10 (maybe by using wsl). So when I search twitter.com, for example, it doesn't go to Google or Cloudflare servers. First it searches on my computer for cached pictures, fonts, etc., then it connects to Twitter servers directly and gets new content.

I want to do this because internet is very expensive and slow in my country, and because of censorship, I have to use a VPN, which makes it even slower.

So, is there a way to cache almost everything and only get the new content from the internet? I know chrome caches a lot of things but i think there are more things that can be cached.

I tried Pi-Hole using Docker, but I created a mess because I didn't know what I was doing and there was no good tutorial for Windows, and when I made it work, there was no upside to it! It was using about 2.5GB of RAM, so I uninstalled it.

Comment: Normally the browser should do it for you.

Comment: @harrymc yes and it's doing a really good job, but i want to know if there is a better and faster way that can help me save time or money.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "caching proxy server". And it is in most cases not really worthwhile as most of the web-based internet content these days doesn't really benefit from extra caching (beyond what the browser is already doing) anyway. A proxy effectively is a browser-cache shared by multiple users. It only makes sense if you have multiple computers/users that frequently visit the same sites. A good adblocker is usually more effective by preventing a lot of ads (that are often not cache-able and multimedia heavy) from being loaded in the first place.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks. I have an adblocker extension and i relocated chrome userdata folder to a RAMDisk so it load sites a lot faster than before. This is probably as far as i can go.